# could not start boa constructor on windows with python2.7

Tags: windows, python-2.7, wxpython, boa-constructor, boa

I am trying to install `Boa Constructor` on windows 7. I am using python 27. 
After installing when i run Boa.py it gave me an error

```
Starting Boa Constructor v0.6.1
importing wxPython
reading user preferences
Created directory: C:\Users\SONY\.boa-constructor
Created directory: C:\Users\SONY\.boa-constructor\docs-cache
Created directory: C:\Users\SONY\.boa-constructor\Plug-ins
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\boa-constructor\Boa.py", line 271, in <mod
ule>
    import Preferences, Utils
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\boa-constructor\Preferences.py", line 151,
 in <module>
    execfile(file)
  File "C:\Users\SONY\.boa-constructor\prefs.rc.py", line 26, in <module>
    splitterStyle = wx.SP_LIVE_UPDATE | wx.SP_3DSASH | wx.NO_3D
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NO_3D'
```

Can somebody please help

Comment: Try using an up to date rad tool such as wxformbuilder

Answer (score 1):

Boa Constructor appears to be importing wx incorrectly. It should not be doing this: `import wxPython`. That was deprecated many years ago. I am guessing you are using wxPython 3.x, which Boa Constructor does not support. If you want to continue using this tool, you will have to downgrade your wxPython installation.

Comment: No the problem was with the NO_3D not defined .. once i defined it in the __init__ method to 0...  it worked

Comment: If you're defining it yourself, then that just proves the issue I was talking about. wxPython has removed wx.NO_3D. You should read this other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304450/can-not-start-boa-constructor-successfully as it sounds like you may need to modify Boa Constructor's source to completely get rid of this issue.

Comment: yeah after defining that value it is working fine .. i am able to create and run my gui perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same problem and downgrading to wxPython version 2.8.12.1 worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using Boa you might want to look at this fork of it.

https://bitbucket.org/cwt/boa-constructor

Looks pretty active and seems to be running against recent versions of wxPython.

Answer (score 0):

to run the BOA Constructor in Python 2.7, you can use **wxPython version 2.8.11.0. or 2.8.12.1**

for a more complete solution, you can read it here :
http://sourceforge.net/p/boa-constructor/discussion/5483/thread/e6f45f66/

to download wxpython version above, please go to here :
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#wxpython